# Thinkscript Probabilty Statistics Study- Need help finishing

Tags: stock, trading, thinkscript

I'm trying to figure the probability that if a stock moves .05 up at the open, what are the chances it will move .50 up? Running into a few hiccups.

This idea comes from a forex trader, "TheRumpledOne." He calls it the “Buyzone.” Check him out if you don't know of him. Think of it as a probability based opening range.

Once you load up the code you can see the numbers should not be more than "barsago" length.

**EDIT:** figured it out. Added "crosses above" to the code. Although there must be a better, “cleaner” way? Also added  "...var and..." to this portion of code which idk if it's really needed.

```
def countsells = Sum( var and var1, barsago);
```

**EDIT 2:**
**This is my current issue.**
Something else is still off. The numbers don't seem right. Now they seem low. I would expect some stocks to hit open + .50 more than 70% of the time but this indicator says differently.

```
# (Probabilty of XYZ FROM THE LAST / PAST XYZ BARS )
# Original/base code By XeoNoX via Usethinkscript.com
# Idea by TheRumpledOne
# By Prison Mike
input barsago = 100;
input buy= .05;
def buyzone= (open + buy);
def var = close crosses above buyzone;
def count = Sum(var, barsago);
AddLabel (yes, "COUNT " +  (count)  );
def pct= round(count/barsago)*100;
AddLabel (yes, "BuyZone " +  (pct)  );

input Sell= .50;
def sellzone= (open + sell);
def var1 =close crosses above  sellzone;
def countsells = Sum(var and var1, barsago);
AddLabel (yes, "COUNT " +  (countsells)  );
def pct2=round (countsells/barsago)*100;
AddLabel (yes, "SellZone " +  (pct2)  );
```

Comment: Make sure your use of *`round()`* is doing what you expect. The rounding implementation on most trading platforms suck, and don't do what you think. This is true for both *PineScript* and *MQL4* and probably many others.

Comment: Seem ok from [here](https://tlc.thinkorswim.com/center/reference/thinkScript/tutorials/Basic/Chapter-2---Mathematical-Functions). But you should test it anyway to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, TRO discusses this on [Stockfetcher's forum thread "A 'Milking the Cows' Dashboard Filter" from 2007](https://www.stockfetcher.com/sfforums/?mid=55466)

Answer (score 0):

A modification: it counts how many bars are in the displayed chart (note: TheRumpledOne's algorithm was designed for intraday trading). It places an orange up-arrow on the price chart wherever the open has gone up by 5 cents; and it places a green arrow wherever the price went up 50 cents. It then shows labels with the counts, percents, and the number of bars (`highestBar` value) that it used for calculating the percent values.

And, I agree: on an AAPL chart, counting approximately 360 15-minute bars, I got a little over 30% that went to 5 cents, and only about 3% that went up 50 cents. That's off the total number of bars; however, when I added the part to calculate the percent of sell count only, I still only got about 8%. Not anywhere near the suggested numbers in [TheRumpledOne's Stockfetcher post](https://www.stockfetcher.com/sfforums/?mid=55466).

Note: the chart I was using to test included out-of-hours bars. Perhaps if I excluded out-of-hours, the numbers would look better? Considering where I got arrows, I don't think so...

Here's the modified script:

```
#hint: from SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66232117/1107226\nThinkscript Probabilty Statistics Study- Need help finishing

def highestBar = HighestAll(BarNumber());

### buy zone ###
input buy = .05;
def buyzone = (open + buy);
plot hitBuyZone = close >= buyzone;
hitBuyZone.SetPaintingStrategy(PaintingStrategy.BOOLEAN_ARROW_UP);
hitBuyZone.setDefaultColor( Color.ORANGE );

def count = if hitBuyZone then count[1] + 1 else count[1];
AddLabel (yes, " BUY COUNT: " + count + " ", Color.YELLOW );
def pct = Round(count / highestBar) * 100;
AddLabel (yes, " BuyZone %: " + (pct) + " ", Color.YELLOW );

### sell zone ###
input Sell = .50;
def sellzone = (open + Sell);
plot hitSellZone = close >= sellzone;
hitSellZone.SetPaintingStrategy(PaintingStrategy.BOOLEAN_ARROW_DOWN);
hitSellZone.SetDefaultColor( Color.GREEN );

def countsells = if hitSellZone then countsells[1] + 1 else countsells[1];
AddLabel (yes, " SELL COUNT: " +  (countsells) + " ", Color.YELLOW );
def pct2 = Round (countsells / highestBar) * 100;
AddLabel (yes, " SellZone %: " +  (pct2) + " ", Color.YELLOW );

### percent of buy count that made it to the full buyzone cents ###
def pctOfBuyCount = Round (countsells / count) * 100;
AddLabel (yes, " Buy Count % of Sell Count: " +  (pctOfBuyCount) + " ", Color.YELLOW );

### show bar count ###
AddLabel(BarNumber() == highestBar, " Bars Counted for %: " + BarNumber() + " ", Color.ORANGE);
```